# How to create grid on button in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I need to create a custom button, on what i have to create grid and on this grid I need to create several labels with specific informations. 
This is code where i`m adding child to button

```
    private void HighlightTodayDay()
    {
        Label label1 = new Label()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.DarkRed,
            Text = "lbl1"
        };

        Label label2 = new Label()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Gold,
            Text = "lbl2"
        };

        if ((DateTime.Today.Year == actualVisibleMonth.Year) && (DateTime.Today.Month == actualVisibleMonth.Month))
        {
            foreach (var child in Children.Reverse())
            {
                if (child.ClassId.ToString() == ("actualDayButtonID" + DateTime.Today.Day.ToString()) && child.IsEnabled == true)
                {
                    DayButton todayDayButton = dayButtonsList[DateTime.Today.Day + shiftOfFirstDay];
                    todayDayButton.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#0f0");
                    //upto this line everything is working as it should
                    todayDayButton.insideGrid.Children.Add(label1, 0, 0);  //do nothing
                    todayDayButton.insideGrid.Children.Add(label2, 0, 1); //do nothing
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is code from "custom" button

```
    class DayButton : Button
{
    public string EventDate;
    public string EventStartTime;
    public string EventEndTime;
    public string EventShift;
    public string EventName;
    public string EventDescription;
    public Grid insideGrid;

    public DayButton()
    {
        insideGrid = new Grid();
        insideGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        insideGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) });
        insideGrid.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

It should look like this [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lugq.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this will work.  You should be able to create a grid and use a TappedGestured to make it act like a button.  Or, if you explain what you're actually trying to accomplish, we may be able to offer a better alternative.

Comment: I need to create own calendar control looking like calendar.google.com,
this button on what i want put grid is in parent grid soo this should be like:
grid with labels =put on> button showing info about day[done] =put on> main grid[done]
and this must be like it is :/
I saw that something like this is possible in WPF [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453047/how-to-make-a-grid-inside-a-button-have-100-percent-width-in-wpf)

Comment: You can create that button using frames? And inside the frame add 2 buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to dismiss button and change it to stack layout (sick!) and to this stacklayout i`m adding new label with events!
soo code look like this:

```
public partial class Calendar : Grid
{...

    public delegate void OnDayClickedDelegate(DateTime dateOfClickedDay);
    public event OnDayClickedDelegate OnDayClicked;
...
        private void DayClick(DateTime clickedDate)
    {
        OnDayClicked(clickedDate);
    }
...
private void SomeVoid()
{...
 DayLayout eventInDay = dayLayoutList[dayID];
                var eventLabel = new Label
                {
                    BackgroundColor = color,
                    Text = name.ToUpper(),
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
                };
                eventInDay.Children.Add(eventLabel);
...}
```

}

and day view

```
        private class DayLayout : StackLayout
    {
        public delegate void OnClickedDelegate(DateTime dateOfClickedDay);
        public event OnClickedDelegate OnClicked;

        public Label DayNumber;

        public DayLayout(DateTime day)
        {
            GestureRecognizers.Add
            (
                new TapGestureRecognizer
                {
                    Command = new Command(() => OnClicked(day))
                }
            );

            var dayNumber = new Label
            {
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
                Text = day.ToString("dd"),
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)),
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
            };

            DayNumber = dayNumber;
            this.Children.Add(DayNumber);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a GestureRecognizer to the Grid and then bind the tap event.

Ex of button code (now a ContentView):

```
            class DayButton : ContentView
        {
            public string EventDate;
            public string EventStartTime;
            public string EventEndTime;
            public string EventShift;
            public string EventName;
            public string EventDescription;
            public Grid insideGrid;

            public event EventHandler Clicked;

            private TapGestureRecognizer _buttonTap;
            private Lable _ButtonText;

            public DayButton()
            {
                _ButtonText = new Lable 
                { 
                      Text = EventName
                }

                insideGrid = new Grid
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowSpacing = 0,

                RowDefinitions =
                {
                    new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto} //0
                },
                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition {Width = GridLength.Star} //0
                }
            };

               //Add your elements to the grid
               insideGrid.Children.Add(_ButtonText, 0, 1, 0, 1)

               //Set the grid as the content of this view
               Content = insideGrid;



                _buttonTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                this.GestureRecognizers.Add(_buttonTap);
                _buttonTap.Tapped += ButtonClicked;
            }
        }

            private async void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (this.IsEnabled)
                {
                    Clicked?.Invoke(this, e);
                }

            }
```

Then you can bind the "Clicked" event where you implement the button.

```
private DayButton _btn1 = new DayButton(){ EventName = "FooBaar"};

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   _btn1.Clicked += OnDayBtnClicked;
   base.OnAppearing();
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   _btn1.Clicked -= OnDayBtnClicked;
   base.OnDisappearing();
}

private void OnDayBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //What to do when a button is clicked
}
```